# Why is my django bulk database population so slow and frequently failing?

Tags: database, django, django-models, sqlite

I decided I'd like to use django's model system rather than coding raw SQL to interface with my database, but I am having a problem that surely is avoidable.

My models.py contains:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    student_id = models.IntegerField(unique = True)
    form = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    preferred = models.CharField(max_length = 70)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length = 70)
```

and I'm populating it by looping through a list as follows:

```
from models import Student

for id, frm, pref, sname in large_list_of_data: 
   s = Student(student_id = id, form = frm, preferred = pref, surname = sname)
   s.save()
```

I don't really want to be saving this to the database each time but I don't know another way to get django to not forget about it (I'd rather add all the rows and then do a single commit).

There are two problems with the code as it stands.

1. It's slow -- about 20 students get updated each second.
2. It doesn't even make it through large_list_of_data, instead throwing a DatabaseError saying "unable to open database file". (Possibly because I'm using sqlite3.)

My question is: How can I stop these two things from happening? I'm guessing that the root of both problems is that I've got the s.save() but I don't see a way of easily batching the students up and then saving them in one commit to the database.

Comment: If I'm getting your question, I guess u can use django ModelForm's which is a far better and cleaner way to save values into ur database. If I m write plz do reply

Comment: @Prateek -- No I'm not interested in creating forms for adding data -- I'm populating the database automatically from the large_list_of_data. The interface for manually adding more data is a separate issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So it seems I should have looked harder before posing the question.

Some solutions are described [in this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136106/efficent-way-to-insert-thousands-of-records-into-a-table-sqlite-python-django) (the winning answer is to use django.db.transaction.commit_manually) and also [in this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395236/aggregating-saves-in-django) on aggregating saves.

Other ideas for speeding up this type of operation are listed in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294088/how-to-accelerate-bulk-insert-to-db-with-djangos-orm).