# Saving many Django objects with one big INSERT statement

Tags: python, django

Imagine you have the following situation:

```
for i in xrange(100000):
  account = Account()
  account.foo = i
  account.save
```

Obviously, the 100,000 `INSERT` statements executed by Django are going to take some time. It would be nicer to be able to combine all those `INSERT`s into one big `INSERT`. Here's the kind of thing I'm hoping I can do:

```
inserts = []

for i in xrange(100000):
  account = Account()
  account.foo = i
  inserts.append(account.insert_sql)

sql = 'INSERT INTO whatever... ' + ', '.join(inserts)
```

Is there a way to do this using QuerySet, without manually generating all those `INSERT` statements?

Comment: Not the same, but possible related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136106/efficent-way-to-insert-thousands-of-records-into-a-table-sqlite-python-django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use raw SQL.

Either by `Account.objects.raw()` or using a django.db.connection objects.

This might not be an option if you want to maintain database agnosticism.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/

If what you're doing is a one time setup, perhaps using a fixture would be better.

Comment: This is what I was trying to avoid, but looking at the other answers/comments, it looks like this might be what I have to do.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 8):

As shown [in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1136106/115845), one can use [@transaction.commit_manually](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.commit_manually) to combine all the `.save()` operations as a single commit to greatly improve performance.

```
@transaction.commit_manually
def your_view(request):
    try:
        for i in xrange(100000):
            account = Account()
            account.foo = i
            account.save()   
    except: 
        transaction.rollback()
    else:
        transaction.commit()
```

Alternatively, if you're feeling adventurous, have a look at [this snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/446/) which implements a manager for bulk inserting. Note that it works only with MySQL, and hasn't been updated in a while so it's hard to tell if it will play nice with newer versions of Django.

Comment: This will make little difference on most engines, except possibly SQLite.  You're still instantiating thousands of models and running thousands of separate SQL inserts.

Comment: (More accurately, it depends on the database backend and configuration; it's likely to help, but in my experience using batch `INSERT INTO ... FROM VALUES` matters a lot more.)

Comment: I'm using MySQL InnoDB and MyISAM and it such approach really does make a difference (more than 100 times faster)