# Quick database update based on previous value in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-1.10

I have a QuerySet which contains `Page` objects, which have `page_number` attribute. The QuerySet is sorted by `page_number`, so running `[i.page_number for i in pages_query_set]` would return something like, for example, `[1,2,3,5,6,10,11,13,16,19,21]`. My task is to write a method that moves the `Page` objects so they would be consecutive: in this example, the page that was 5 would become 4, 6 would become 5, 10 would be 6, 11 is 7, 13 is 8, etc.

This is my initial solution, a method inside `PageQuerySet` class:

```
def validatePageNumbers(self):
    prev_page = 0
    for page in self:
        if page.page_number > prev_page+1:
            page.page_number = prev_page+1
            page.save()
        prev_page = page.page_number
```

Functionally, it works fine. But calling `save()` every time really slows it down (probably due to calling database queries every time). I need to find a faster approach. If there had been only one "gap" in this sequence, I would just slice the QuerySet and use something like `sliced_qs.update(page_number=models.F('page_number')-gap)`, because I've seen a singular `update()` being much faster than several `save()`. But the gaps are multiple and pretty random.

So I'm confused. `F` objects don't seem to support such looping. It would be great if I could use a callable in `update()`, but I haven't found any information about that in docs, nor it works when I try it. Is there a way to apply `update()` here? Or maybe some other way to make this method faster?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this and numerous other bottlenecks was quite simple.

```
from django.db import transaction

with transaction.atomic():
    #do stuff here
```

Guess it wraps it all into a single transaction and hits the database only once. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1136248/2052138) has helped a lot here.